# Heat Conduction/Convection Along discontinuous tube

Tags: heat-transfer, thermal-conduction, convection

I have a question regarding heat conduction/convection. I have a metallic tube over which a rope heater is wound, supplying power. A glass tube and a 2nd metallic tube lies at the exit of the first tube. The inlet thermocouple is placed at the inlet of the first metallic section, and exit thermocouple is placed at the end of the 2nd metallic tube.  Assuming I am supplying 500 W of heat to the rope heater, would I be getting 500 W of heat at the exit of the first metallic section (before the glass tube and second metallic tube) or is the 500 W only available at end of the 2nd metallic tube (meaning significantly less power available at the exit of the 1st metallic tube)? The discontinuity with the heater and glass section in the middle has me confused. 
Thanks!

Comment: If the glass and second tube are insulated, the heat temperature at the exit of the first tube and the exit of the second would be roughly the same.  The heat would be transferred in for the length of the rope heater.  Note that if the heater is 500W, you will get less than that into the tube, since some of the heat will go to the environment.